# Is there a way i can read a list as individual variables in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

So to preface, i am very new to python (started about a week ago). I wanted to test my skills and create a program that allows the user to input a set of data into a list at which point it would be sorted and printed out into an array of positive varibles and negative ones.

```
numbers = list(map(float, input( 'Enter numbers: \n').split()))
positive_num=[]
negative_num=[]
for x in numbers:
    if numbers >0:
        positive_num.append(numbers)
    elif numbers <0:
         negative_num.appenend(numbers())

print('positive numbers: ' + positive_num)
print('negative numbers: ' + negative_num)
print("nuetral number: 0")
```

if im on the right path, its not working because `numbers` is a list and `>0` is a variable so it cant compare the two. So all in all, the question im trying to get at is how do i make the list take each individual variable and test it against > or < to 0 so that i can put it into the array?

Maybe i did eveything all wrong at this point im pretty lost. Any help and explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if x > 0 ... positive_num.append(x)` `if x < 0 ...`? you are already going over each element of `numbers`

Comment: Use `x` in comparison.

Comment: " its not working because numbers is a list and >0 is a variable" `>0` is not a variable, it is part of an expression involving the `>` operator and the `int` literal `0`. It doesn't work because `numbers` is a `list` object and `0` is an `int` object which do not support the `>` operator between them

Comment: You should use `x` instead of `numbers` in comparison and then append `x` to the corresponding num list.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `x` points to each item of the list as you iterate through the list, so, you should be doing the comparison using `x` rather than using `numbers` which is the entire list. Similarly, you should also be appending `x` and not `numbers`.

```
for x in numbers:
    if numbers >0:
        positive_num.append(numbers)
    elif numbers <0:
        negative_num.appenend(numbers())
```

should be

```
for x in numbers:
    if x > 0:
        positive_num.append(x)
    elif x < 0:
         negative_num.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are awesome too:

```
positive_num = [n for n in numbers if n > 0]
negitive_num = [n for n in numbers if n < 0]
```

Although only drawback here is you’re effectively looping twice

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that should fix your errors:

```
numbers = list(map(float, input( 'Enter numbers: \n').split()))
positive_num=[]
negative_num=[]
for x in numbers:
    if x >0:
        positive_num.append(x)
    elif x <0:
         negative_num.append(x)

print('positive numbers: ', positive_num)
print('negative numbers: ', negative_num)
print("nuetral number: 0")
```